# How to analyze Git submodules using SonarCloud?

Tags: maven, github, travis-ci, sonarcloud

I'm currently trying to setup a Maven multi-module project in order to gather some metrics. Some of these modules are GitHub submodules and they don't show up when running the SonarCloud analysis.

We're using Travis CI and I have configured SonarCloud in the .travis.yml file.

```
addons:
    sonarcloud:
        organization: "my-organization"
        token:
            secure: "my-token"
```

I expected the analysis to go through all of the sources (and it apparently does, see the log at https://travis-ci.org/atlanmod/atlanmod-platform, starting line 4753), but only "regular" modules are actually analyzed and not the Git submodules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.
You actually need to set the parameter sonar.scm.exclusions.disabled to true.
Here's what the .travis.yml looks like :

```
script:
   - mvn clean install
   - mvn -Dsonar.scm.exclusions.disabled sonar:sonar
```